# AJAX get request puts each letter into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Below I have a AJAX get request. The index.php file called returns the data in JSON format. What I want to do is have that data put into a JavaScript array. Currently what I have works, however the array puts each different letter into an array.

```
$.get('../poll/index.php?data=vehicles', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        vehicles.push(data[i]);
    }
    console.log(vehicles);
});
```

[image]

Am I forgetting to do something?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't not parse the response. See [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196). If you'd set [the correct content type response header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/267546/218196), jQuery would parse it automatically for you. Alternatively you can pass `'json'` as fourth parameter to `$.get`.

Comment: In the PHP file I set the response header: CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json')

Comment: That seems to be the header for a request made through curl though, not a header for the Ajax response.

Comment: Ahh, so what do I do instead to correct that?

Comment: @FelixKling is correct, the `data` you `get` is a `string` now. You should parse it into `JSON` or use the `json` as the fourth parameter.

Comment: As I said: (a) Parse the JSON, or (b) set the header properly (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), or (c) pass `'json'` as third/fourth argument to `$.get`.

Comment: @Dylengleng: No, you don't parse it *into* JSON. The data *is* JSON. The JSON has to be parsed into an array (or object).

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, yes, I have a wrong understanding of JSON.

Comment: `for (var i in vehicles){ vehicles[i] = vehicles[i].join(""); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is a string containing JSON, it is not an array. You have four options to convert the response (JSON) in a JavaScript data type (array or object):

1. Parse the JSON explicitly: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196)
2. Set the proper content type response header to let jQuery automatically parse the response for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/267546/218196
3. Tell jQuery about the format of the response, so that it parses it for you. For that, pass `'json'` as the last argument to [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).
4. Use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), which is equivalent to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('../poll/index.php?data=vehicles', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        vehicles.push(data[i]);
    }
    console.log(vehicles);
});
```

Comment: I've just tried this but it's not logging anything to the console. :(

Comment: @Joel: Make sure the JSON is valid (http://jsonlint.org/). Use `json_encode` to generate the JSON (if you don't do that already).

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's the JSON that's the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery.getJSON() instead of jQuery.get(). Currently your request expect to receive raw text, i.e. array of characters.

See the official documentations [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), but in you case it's the same use